# T-SQL losing records in a JOIN in SQL Server 2012

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables I am trying to pull data from in SQL Server 2012.  I am losing records from the BO table from the JOIN to the PO table on the ItemNumber.  How can I resolve this?  The BO table query originally pulls 309 rows and the full query pulls 280 rows.  I know there are Items that do not exist in the PO table that do exist in the BO table, but I still need to see those in the final results so I can say they are unaccounted for.

```
SELECT
    a.ItemNumber,
    a.BOQty,
    a.TtlBO$,
    MIN(po.PBDUE) AS PODueDate
FROM
    dbo.PO po
    RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT
    bo.ItemNumber,
    SUM(bo.BOQty) AS BOQty,
    SUM(bo.ExtPrice) AS TtlBO$
FROM
    dbo.BO bo
GROUP BY
    bo.ItemNumber
)a
ON a.ItemNumber = po.PBITEM
WHERE po.PBTYPE <> 'R'
  AND po.PASTAT <> 'X'
GROUP BY
    a.ItemNumber,
    a.BOQty,
    a.TtlBO$
ORDER BY
    ItemNumber
```

Comment: you need to add the condition for null, for example, OR po.pbtype is null

Comment: It wouldn't be the po.pbtype I think.  I think it would be po.pbitem is null, but that still doesn't capture all my missing items.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to get what I needed:

```
SELECT
        a.ItemNumber,
        a.BOQty,
        a.TtlBO$,
        MIN(po.PBDUE) AS PODueDate
    FROM
        dbo.PO po
        RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT
        bo.ItemNumber,
        SUM(bo.BOQty) AS BOQty,
        SUM(bo.ExtPrice) AS TtlBO$
    FROM
        dbo.BO bo
    GROUP BY
        bo.ItemNumber
    )a
    ON a.ItemNumber = po.PBITEM AND po.PBTYPE <> 'R' AND po.PASTAT <> 'X'
      OR po.PBITEM IS NULL
    GROUP BY
        a.ItemNumber,
        a.BOQty,
        a.TtlBO$
    ORDER BY
        ItemNumber
```

Comment: yes, that was the suggestion of adding the condition for null I gave you; all the columns in PO will be null when there is no match